# How can I run an individual request with Postman Collection Runner?

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I want to use the Postman Collection Runner to submit requests to an XML API based on data [imported from a CSV spreadsheet](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/10/28/using-csv-and-json-files-in-the-postman-collection-runner/). However, rather than running an entire collection, I want to only run an ***individual*** request from a folder.

So for example: I have a folder of POST requests for manipulating employee data.

[image: POST requests for employee data]

I specifically want to test sending `Load` requests to my API. However, the Collection Runner only lets me select and run the entire `Personality` folder.

**How can I test an individual request using the Postman Collection Runner?**

Answer (score 3):

You could also simply create a subfolder for the single request you want to iterate over. Runner can zoom in on that folder.

Comment: Agreed. So we have presented several different ways it *can* be done.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the first request you can use the `setNextRequest(null)` function within the `test` tab. As long as the request that you only want to run is first in the collection, it will be the only one that is picked up in the collection runner. More details can be found [here](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/building_workflows).

Comment: The request I want to run isn’t first in the collection unfortunately.

Comment: Create a collection with a single request or move the collection up to be the first one? Both will work for what you’re asking, just depends what you do and don’t want to change.

Comment: Or in the first request comment out any tests and use the setNextRequest("Load") so it goes to that request and still keep the null option in that test to stop the runner

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Do any of the proposed solutions answer your question?

Comment: They are decent workarounds, but they weren’t exactly what I was looking for unfortunately.

Comment: Share and update, if you find the solution you’re after.

Answer (score 0):

Select the collections tab on the left hand side.   Tap on the name of the collection to expand all the requests in the collection. Select the request you want to run.  In the right hand window, the request will show up.  Hit the send button to run the request.

Of course this is not directly from the collection runner itself.